# Lotusscript date time issues

Tags: datetime, lotusscript

I have a couple of dates stored in a view. And I am using getItemValue to retrieve them.

`Dim repsondedDate As NotesDateTime`
`Set repsondedDate = timePart1doc.GetItemValue("dateResponded")`

When I try to do the following, I get a type missmatch at run time.

`Dim dateDifference As double

Set dtLocal = New NotesDateTime( Now )

dateDifference = repsondedDate.Timedifference(dtLocal)`

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line returns an array:

```
Set repsondedDate = timePart1doc.GetItemValue("dateResponded")
```

So it should be:

```
Set repsondedDate = timePart1doc.GetItemValue("dateResponded")(0)
```

If I'm not mistaken you should be using the GetItemValueDateTimeArray method instead of the GetItemValue, so it should actually be like this:

```
Set repsondedDate = timePart1doc.GetItemValueDateTimeArray("dateResponded")(0)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think your answer solved 3/4 of my problem.  I guess, if dateResponded is blank in the view, then the assignment to respondedDate fails with type mismatch.  Seems odd, but a little checking plus your suggestion has me on my way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use GetItemValueDateTimeArray instead like the [IBM example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLES_GETITEMVALUEDATETIMEARRAY_METHOD.html) below:

```
Sub Initialize
  Dim session As New NotesSession
  Dim db As NotesDatabase
  Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
  Dim doc As NotesDocument
  Dim count As Integer
  Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
  Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
  If dc.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
  Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
  Dim times As Variant
  times = doc.GetItemValueDateTimeArray("Times")
  count = 0
  Forall t In times
    count = count + 1
    If Typename(t) = "NOTESDATETIME" Then
      Messagebox t.LocalTime,, "Date/time # " & count
    Elseif Typename(t) = "NOTESDATERANGE" Then
      Messagebox t.StartDateTime.LocalTime & " - " & _
      t.EndDateTime.LocalTime,, "Date/time # " & count
    End If
  End Forall
End Sub
```